# bloomberg api refresh not working when excel launched via cscript.exe

Tags: bloomberg

I have a macro that works perfectly when I run manually.  The first thing it does is refresh the Bloomberg data links...

```
Application.Run "RefreshAllWorkbooks"
Application.Run "RefreshAllStaticData"
```

I want to automate the task so I have windows scheduler using cscript.exe open excel and launch the macro.  Unfortunately I am getting an error... the vba macro launches, but when I get to the refresh bloomberg links code I get the error.
macro may not be available.
When I click on the manual refresh bloomberg I get another error.
unable to launch this component, check if excel is in edit mode.

I believe it has to do with cscript not launching the bloomberg add-ins to excel.

does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Is excel getting launched under your user account?

Comment: i believe it is... just the bloomberg add in is not getting loaded

Comment: Bloomberg does a lot asynchronously: ie Excel makes a Bloomberg call which returns immediately. The result is provided later via a callback. This can give problems if Excel doesn’t get the chance to execute the callback function. What might be happening is that the Bloomberg addin is initializing asynchronously and never gets a chance to finish, because your macro is being called immediately. One suggestion is to use the Application.OnTime method to call your macro with a delay, which could Bloomi time to do its thing …

Comment: once i put this line it the bloomberg add in was loaded successfully.  l.Workbooks.Open ("C:\blp\API\Office Tools\BloombergUI.xla")